# SharePoint 2016 - how to create a site map in SharePoint 216 using SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server

Client has this requirement where Links should store in sharePoint list  where user can manage, user could enable or disable it from the sharepoint list itself.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint List may not be an good option for you to create a site map. By default, for SharePoint 2016, you can go o site content and structure to see the [SharePoint site structure](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-generate-a-site-map-of-sharepoint-sites/d2cb9aee-65ae-417b-9372-64b3d45241fb). Or in other words, it is like a site map.

And for the requirement enable and disable by user, [Managed Navigation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-managed-navigation-for-a-site-in-sharepoint-49a067dc-77d2-455d-9e77-250ec7cc0a6d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) may be a choice, you can edit the term set used for the managed navigation for end users to use.

One more thing you can try is the [Promoted Links](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-add-sharepoint-tiles-promoted-links-to-your-site/) app. It provides you a more easily out of box solution for users to add/delete links and add it as a web part in pages you like